# How to mark up the "isAccessoryOrSparePartFor" property for a replacement part?

Tags: schema.org, microdata, rich-snippets, products

I want to create a rich snippet for a replacement valve for a kitchen faucet.

How do I associate that part to the parent product using Microdata and the `isAccessoryOrSparePartFor` property?

This is what I have so far:

```html
<div itemprop="isAccessoryOrSparePartFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Replacement Valve 209438</h1>
  <link itemprop="url" href="https://www.example/replacement-valve-209438">
  <link itemprop="model" href="https://www.example.com/kitchen-faucet-220/">
  <!-- more product properties, etc. -->
</div>
```

How should it look in the Google Rich Snippet Tool--should there be one product or two? Is `model` the correct property to associate to the parent faucet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Google’s [Products rich result](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products) doesn’t make use of the [`isAccessoryOrSparePartFor`](http://schema.org/isAccessoryOrSparePartFor) property, so the following is only based on how it can be represented with Schema.org.)

Your structured data conveys: There is a `Product` (not shown) which is an an accessory/spare part for the `Product` "Replacement Valve 209438". But you want it the other way around, as far as I understand it.

So it could look like this:

```html
<article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">

  <h2 itemprop="name">Replacement Valve 209438</h2>

  <div itemprop="isAccessoryOrSparePartFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <a itemprop="url" href="/kitchen-faucet-220">
      <span itemprop="name">Kitchen Faucet 220</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</article>
```

The [`model`](http://schema.org/model) property can be used to reference the `ProductModel` of the `Product` for which (!) you specify the property.

Comment: Thanks, the Google Rich Snippet tool did acknowledge the itemprop and display it in the results. I understand they don't do anything with it, but that's good enough for what I need to do now. Thanks again